# Best practice to send multiple POST API request in foreach

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics-api

I need to create multiple Google Analytics properties programmatically using the GA Admin API - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/create.

It is about 300+ properties so also 300+ post requests with different request bodies. For that, I have an array with those 300+ objects. What would be the best practice in JS to perform all these requests? Can I just loop the array with `forEach` and use the `fetch` function in each iteration?

```
propertyArr.forEach((e, i, a) => {
    gapi.client.request({ 
        path: 'https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties', 
        method: 'POST', 
        body: e
    });
});
```

This is what I have right now. Note I am using [gapi.client.request()](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md#----gapiclientrequestargs--) method to make the call.

Thank you

Comment: You could map the propertyArr to an array of fetch request promises then `await Promise.all()` that array. Something like `await Promise.all(propertyArr.map(prop => ...make request));`. Just don't `await` inside the map (that'll cause each request to be done sequentially).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map over `propertyArr` and use `Promises.allsettled` to ensure all requests are either rejected/resolved

```
const allRequests = propertyArr.map((e, i, a) => {
   return gapi.client.request({ 
       path: 'https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties', 
       method: 'POST', 
       body: e
   });
});
let result = await Promises.allsettled(allRequests ).then(success).catch(error);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach is using Promises in parallel

```
    let promises = [];
    propertyArr.forEach((e, i, a) => {
    promises.push(
    gapi.client.request({ 
        path: 'https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties', 
        method: 'POST', 
        body: e
    }));
});

let result = await Promises.allsettled(promises).then((result) => ....).catch(error);
```

Also If you request are not dependent on each other and you do not want to stop execution when any of the request fails, you can use `Promise.allsettled`

> **Promise.all** will reject as soon as one of the Promises in the array rejects.
>
> **Promise.allSettled** will never reject - it will resolve once all
> Promises in the array have either rejected or resolved.